# Will adding a PCI-E TV card turn off my HDMI port?

Tags: hdmi, pci-express, shuttle

I have a [Shuttle SG45H7](http://uk.shuttle.com/products/productsDetail?productId=1131) which I use as my home theatre PC. Currently I have a DVB-T card in the PCI slot and I connect to my TV by HDMI. This PC has an Intel G45 + ICH10 chipset.

I would like to add a satellite TV card, probably [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Definition-Digital-Satellite-Express-Receiver/dp/B0038LU03K/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1321274161&sr=8-1), to the PCI-E slot. However, the FAQ section of the Shuttle website for my machine [says](http://uk.shuttle.com/products/productsFaqList?productId=1131):

> Why there is no display from onboard digital output (HDMI) when insert PCI-E interface card?
>
> That is cause by the Intel Hard ware design, when you insert PCI-E interface card, the 
>   onboard digital output will not display.

and

> Can the HDMI display when inserting the PCI-E card?
>
> No, it can not.
>   But the D-sub could display in that moment.
>   That is the design limitation of the chipset.

What is the design limitation they refer to, and does it only apply to PCI-E graphics card or will any PCI-E card make the HDMI port stop working? I would prefer to continue using the HDMI connector because I don't then need a separate connection for sound.

**Edit**

This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/247160/pcie-network-card-deactivate-dvi-output-but-not-vga-output-on-shuttle-sg41j1), although that is a different chipset and talks about DVI not HDMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now almost certain that this the same problem as in the linked question. If you look at section 1.6.1.4 in the documentation for a board using the the G45 chipset it appears that the HDMI port will work with a non-Video x1 PCI-E card. Fortunately the card I want to use is PCI-E x1 so it will be fine. A bigger card will cause the HDMI port not to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a limited mastery of English. It's common for on-board video to turn itself off when a *video* card is inserted into the PCI-e slot. This made sense, because that videocard is usually far more powerful (however, modern computers may keep the internal video enabled to drive two monitors in that configuration).

With a PCI-e TV card, the internal video *should* continue to work.

Comment: This is what I was assuming, but the comment about the D-sub still working suggests that the on-board video is still enabled. Like you say though, their English is poor so perhaps they mean the D-sub on the PCI-E graphics card.